# Misconception about surjective morphisms of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

A morphism $f:X\to Y$ of schemes is said to be [surjective](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01RY) if its underlying map of sets is surjective. [Tag 0487](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0487), [Tag 025Z](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/025Z), and [Tag 025T](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/025T) imply that $f$ is surjective if and only if the induced map
$$
f_\ast:X(k)\to Y(k)
$$
is surjective, for every algebraically closed field $k$.

Now, consider the canonical morphism of schemes $f:\mathop{\mathbf{Spec}}\mathbb{C}\to \mathop{\mathbf{Spec}}\mathbb{Q}$, induced by the field extension of the complex numbers over the rational numbers. Obviously, the morphism $f$ is surjective. However, the canonical morphism $\mathop{\mathbf{Spec}}\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\to \mathop{\mathbf{Spec}}\mathbb{Q}$ does not lift to $\mathop{\mathbf{Spec}}\mathbb{C}$, where $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. $f_\ast$ is not surjective for the algebraically closed field $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Could you please help identify what is wrong?

Comment: The theorem in Tag 0487 requires $f$ to be locally of finite type. Your $f$ isn't.